# Difference between usage of room and space

Tags: word-usage

There is no more space for you in this apartment.

There is no more room for you in this car.

How to determine which one to use?

Comment: I would use the second one if I was talking about a car and the first one if I was talking about an apartment.  Apart from that the meaning seems the same to me.

Answer (score 2):

Both room and space are countable and non-countable.It depends on the context. Both room and space have the same meaning when they are defining the capacity of the place. They differ when room is preceded by an article and it is describing the specific place of a building

Example:

(1)There is no space/room for you in the car.

(2)I painted the room white.

You can refer this http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/whats-the-difference-between-space-room.316808/